# boundary of $A ={}$ boundary(interior of $A$)

Tags: general-topology

Let $(M,d)$ be the metric space and $A\in M$.

Let $\operatorname{bd}(A)$ be boundary of $A$, let $\operatorname{int}A$ is interior of $A$.

Is $\operatorname{bd}(A) = \operatorname{bd}(\operatorname{int}A)$?

Comment: I suspect "$A\in M$" should be "$A\subseteq M$".

Answer (score 2):

No. If $A$ is not empty but its interior is, then $\emptyset=\operatorname{bd}(\operatorname{int}A)\subsetneq\operatorname{bd}A$.

Comment: don't we need to verify the existence of "A is not empty but its interior is"?

Comment: @Daschin, Consider $\{0,1\}$ as a subset of $\Bbb{R},$ with the usual (metric) topology.

Comment: set such as $A = \{1\n | n=1,2,3..\}$ is this would be fit for your suggested case?

Comment: @Chickenmancer then the bd({0,1}) = {0,1}?

Comment: Indeed, you should try to provide reasons here so we can provide feedback.

Comment: @Daschin, In any metric space, a set $\{x\}$, where $x$ is a non-isolated point, is an example of a non-empty set with empty interior.

Answer (score 1):

No. For example, take a single point $x$ in $\Bbb R^n$ with standard metric. Its interior is empty, but it is its own boundary. So

$$\mathrm{bd}(\{x\})=\{x\},\qquad \mathrm{bd}(\mathrm{int}(\{x\}))=\mathrm{bd}(\varnothing)=\varnothing.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the rational numbers in $X=\mathbb{R}$, then $\operatorname{int}(A) = \emptyset$, which has empty boundary, while $\operatorname{bd}(A) =\mathbb{R}$, which is quite a bit larger.